# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Tags: java, database, oracle

I get this error when i was inserting some rows to database.

**Code**

```
public class InsertRowData {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager
                 .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL" , "system" , "system");

        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        String dmlinsert = "insert into student(111,manoj,rawatrulz09)";

        int rowseffected = statement.executeUpdate(dmlinsert);      
        System.out.println("no of rows effected" + rowseffected);
        
    }   
}
```

After searching in google I found the solution to remove single quotes from the column but still getting the same error.

Comment: Your insert query should have a `VALUES` part .

Comment: add "values"  ..

Comment: Also the string values needs to be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: you use oracle or mysql? if oracle change tag from mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad approach to insert any data into the Table.

`String dmlinsert="insert into student(111,manoj,rawatrulz09)"`

first of all, your query missing a syntax `Values`.

when columns are not mentioned while inserting, `values` must contain same amount of data and respectively.

But when inserting a data the best practice is to mention columns, so that if in later time you make any change to the table in database, your insert query stays stable.
for e.g:
`insert into student(id, name, email) values(111,'manoj','rawatrulz09')`.

Now, if in future you will add a column to this table, your insert query will still work as it has mentioned columns, but if you won't mention any columns then your code will start giving error when executed `no of values don't match given to the table` etc... Good luck! 
anyway, answer for your insert query:

`insert into student values(111,'manoj','rawatrulz09')`

Comment: You might need some single quotes to actually make this SQL work.